# Modify request parameters in a JSF2 validator

Tags: jsf-2, validation

Is it possible to override request parameters in a JSF2 validator?

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context,
    UIComponent component, Object value)
    throws ValidatorException {

    // can i modify name's value and set it back the new value back?
    final String name = (String) value;

}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to convert a value using a validator instead of a converter?

Comment: Yes, it may be possible, but like BalusC said, you're supposed to be doing that in a converter. What exactly is your use case

Comment: Hi both. My impression of a Converter is to convert from a String to an Object and vice versa. For my use case, i am trying to check if 'name' contains a last name, and if it does, upper case the last name. Do you think i can still use a Converter for this? Thanks!

Comment: @OhChinBoon - You can and should use a converter - "convert" a lower case string to an upper case one

Comment: Hi Balus & Kolossus, thank you for the tip. I did just that.